# Best way to change multiple images color with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, color-picker

I have a shape on a background. I have one jQuery color picker to chose the color of the shape, and one jQuery color picker to change the background color. I need ie6 support.

The shape can be any kind of image.

Changing a div background color behind a negative image of the shape doesn't work, because this way i can only change the color of the shape.

[image]

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) gives you very rich support for exactly the kind of thing you're doing, cross browser, using efficient vector graphics and with (relatively) lightweight code.

Comment: Raphael library looksreally great, but my shape is defined by an image. And i dont find a way to fill only a part of an image with raphael.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a background-color property which you are altering via the color picker and then.... (this part I do not understand) an image inserted in that same div with the background color you are altering? If thats the case I dont get why using a negative wouldn't work with transparency. Is this because the shape might not be a perfect square? could you be more clear?